The response of my google places api is limited to bengaluru
I used the google places api for hotels in my nodejs application, when i run the application locally, i get the list of hotels from everypart of india/world which is the desired response but when i deploy the application on digitalOcean and since the server location is in Bengaluru the hotels search is only limited to bengaluru.
How to fix it?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
